General Gibbs Phenomenon Proof
I understand the easy proof of Gibbs Phenomenon where you first prove it for the (periodically extended) square wave     $f(t) = \begin{cases} 
      c & 0<t<1 \\
      -c & -1 < t < 0      
   \end{cases}$ for some constant $c$ and then use this to write a general "nice enough" function with jump discontinuity as a sum of a function whose Fourier series uniformly converges and a finite sum of square waves.
The question is then whether there's a $\textit{direct}$ proof of Gibbs phenomenon in the general jump discontinuity case that doesn't revert to the square wave case.   I understand that the very explicit nature of the square wave case makes such a proof likely unnecessarily complicated compared to the proof above, but still this is quite interesting of a question I think.

The name is Gibbs phenomenon

Not sure why I wrote it that way!

A nice exposition which provides justifications for the Gibbs Phenomenon appears in Barry Simon's Real Analysis, A comprehensive course in Analysis, Part 1.  This overshot is caused the distribution of mass of the Dirichlet kernel, which causes ripples to form along the graph of a function $f$ around the point of discontinuity evenly in both directions.

I'll take a look at his book.
Something sort of along these lines IS found in "The Gibbs phenomenon" (int. j. math. educ. sci. technol., 2001, vol. 32, no. 1, 73–89).  They still do revert to the square wave function argument as I described.
HOWEVER, they interestingly don't take for granted that the maximum/minimum point of overshoot for a general function f(x) with jump discontinuity should occur at the same place as it does for the square wave (which is at $x_n = 1/2n$ I think) and actually directly proves this in the general case.
